# logstash keeps retrying infinitely when failed to upload to Elasticsearch cluster due to bulk upload error

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, amazon-s3, logstash

logstash keeps retrying infinitely when failed to upload to Elasticsearch cluster due to bulk upload error. It stuck at this error and not processing other logs. Can someone please help me how to resolve this issue?

`[2019-10-09T19:05:38,343] **[ERROR]** [logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Encountered a retryable error. Will Retry with exponential backoff {:code=>413, :url=>"https://elasticsearch.domain:443/_bulk", :body=>"{\"Message\":\"Request size exceeded 10485760 bytes\"}"}`

Comment: You need to either decrease the message size or increase the limit on Ealsticsearch

Comment: @val I am using aws elasticsearch, so I cannot increase the size on elasticsearch, is there any other way to solve this issue?

Comment: @Val when you say **increase the size on elasticsearch,**, do you mean to increase the disk space on server where ElasticSearch is residing?

Comment: @Mahesh no I meant to increase the value of the [http.max_content_length](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html) setting

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using Logstash > 7.6, which was my case too, so the flush no longer works.

In order to change the bulk size add the following parameter in to your output section, available as of 2020/03/04:

`max_bulk_bytes => 9999999`

After that the plugin will automatically set the bulk size.

```
amazon_es {
    hosts => ["monitoring"]
    region => "eu-central-1"
    index => "cloudfront-logs-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    document_id => "%{[x_edge_request_id]}"
    max_bulk_bytes => 9999999
    }
}
```

You might also consider updating your instance type of the ES cluster based on your data:
[AWS ES Network limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-limits.html#network-limits)

See more details on the GitHub plugin page:
[logstash-output-amazon_es](https://github.com/awslabs/logstash-output-amazon_es)

I also tried to change the pipeline size, but it did not work:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/logstash-settings-file.html

Answer (score 0):

aws limit size to 10MB, then maybe you sholud be change your conf Logstash output .. flush_size to 10

```
vim /etc/logstash/conf.d/output
output {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["XXX.XX.XX.XX"]
      index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
      flush_size => 10
      template => "/etc/logstash/template.json"
    }
}
```

Comment: I am seeing this issue when I add flush_size in amazon_es outplut plugin.

 Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException", :message=>"Unable to configure plugins: (ConfigurationError) The setting `flush_size` in plugin `amazon_es` is obsolete and is no longer available. This setting is no longer available as we now try to restrict bulk requests to sane sizes. See the 'Batch Sizes' section of the docs. If you think you still need to restrict payloads based on the number, not size, of events.